# Do all component instances need to be static when adding it to a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, static

For example in the code below you can see that I add a static instance of a character to the JFrame which I called view. Is there anytime that I can add a component that isn't static to view? I am just trying to understand why the component has to be static. is it because the way I have wrote the code?

```
 public class View extends JFrame {
      static  Character mainCharacter;

    public View(){

        this.setBackground(Color.black);
        this.setSize(800,600);
       // JLayeredPane pane = new JLayeredPane();
         mainCharacter = new Character();

    }

        public static void main(String[] args){
            View view = new View();

            view.add(mainCharacter);




        view.setVisible(true);
        view.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);



    }
```

Comment: No, none of your components should be static. If you are using static methods or variables like this then that is an indication of a poorly designed GUI. Look at the examples from the [Swing Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html) for a better way to start building your GUI's. You should not even be extending JFrame. Again look at several examples from the tutorial. Start with something simple, like `How to Use Labels`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable is `static` as you're accessing it from the `main` method which is not associated with the instance of `View`. Place the variable in method or the constructor. Unless you need to access the variable outside the scope of use, it should be defined as a local variable

```
void initComponents() {

    ...
    Character mainCharacter = new Character();
    frame.add(mainCharacter);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much guys! :) I'm just trying to improve my code for the sake of being a better programmer and you guys definitely helped me! I just have one quick question, Why is it a bad Idea to extend JFrame? What problems could I run into by doing this? What should be done instead?

Comment: You're not adding new functionality to the frame so there's no need to extend it. Simply create an instance of the class and add components to that instance

Answer (score 2):

Components dont have to be static to be added to a Frame. In your case `mainCharacter` has to be static because you are using it inside a static method, namely the `main` method.